# ASP.NET and unverifiable components

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET application. I need to use some third party component (do not have the source code) that is unverifiable (I think it is written in managed c++).

I am wondering if this can cause problems for the customers.
The ASP.NET application can be installed on the customers servers or potentially on some hosted server.

What are the problems that I/customers may get into?

Comment: I am mostly concerned about the assembly being unverifiable. 
I do not think there are dependencies on other components, although I will double check this. 
I thought maybe In some asp.net configurations code access security causes problems with unverifiable components.

Answer (score 1):

You have to test these yourself. Potentially the problems that can crop up are:

- Improper registering of COM DLLs -- you have to test your application installer to make sure this doesn't happen
- Registry complications - some third party components set registry entries that can only be entered using *their own installer*, rendering it impossible for you to properly install the component yourself. In that case you have to bootstrap their installer to yours.
- Unknown dependencies -- if your third party components have dependencies to other components that are not obvious
- Unknown requirements -- if your third party component has specific hardware requirements, they might fail.
- Unclear environment requirements -- some third party components can run on Windows Server 2000 or 2003, but not on 2008, or vice-versa

All of these can be mitigated by testing your final application installer on vanilla (plain-Windows) servers which represent a good sample of your targeted server OSs: Windows Server 2000, 2003, 2008. You should also test your application against freshly-installed instances of IIS 5, 6, and 7.

Consequently, if you wish to target Mono, you have to make further tests on various Linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to ensure that you're using the same .NET Framework version as your customer. Also note the dependencies/requirements of that third party component; if those are not present in your customer's machines then it won't work.